# How to perform Binary Search Operation of a text file in memory using java?

Tags: java

How can we perform binary search operation on a text file in java after loading it into the memory ?
I ve tried using RandomAccessFile but it takes a lot of time as it does'nt load the file into memory. Is there any other alternative to this ?
My file size is 30 MB

Comment: Please show the code you wrote so far. Without a more clear description where you are stuck, we cant really help.

Comment: Do all lines have equal length? What is the search key - the entire line? How many lines? Have you tried reading all of the file into a String[]?

Comment: I think the question requires a bit more of context. In order to run binary search, you have to run on a sorted list. This presumably means your file is either binary or it contains structured text (how would you know where to jump to, otherwise?). Could you tell us more about the kind of structure you are working on? In principle, the OS *will* load parts of the file in memory, regardless of the type of access you specify. But your binary lookup access pattern may defy the IO caching algorithm. Try a sequential search, first. If it's easier and faster, consider sticking to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the file into memory using MappedByteBuffer.

See here:
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/683614/things-to-know-about-memory-mapped-file-in-java